# Fixed point of a polynomial mapping - what's the relation between the two views

Tags: polynomials, fixed-point-theorems

Let $\sigma : \Bbb{C}^3 \to \Bbb{C}^3$ be a polynomial mapping.

Let $P:= \Bbb{C}[x,y,z]$ denote the space of polynomial in 3 variables.

Then $\sigma$ induces a (linear) mapping $\tilde{\sigma} : P\to P$, by
$$p \mapsto \tilde{\sigma}(p) := p\circ \sigma,$$
for $p \in P$.

A fixed point for $\sigma$ is a point $(a,b,c)\in \Bbb{C}^3$, such that $\sigma(a,b,c) = (a,b,c)$, and similarly for $\tilde{\sigma}$.

**Question:** What is the relation, if any, between fixed points for $\sigma$ and for $\tilde{\sigma}$ ?